# How to comment multiple of line by anisble playbook

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I can comment one line by ansible playbook with

```
- name: Comment out a line
  replace:
    dest: /etc/nova/nova.conf
    regexp: '^connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite'
    replace: '#connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite'
  tags: update-nova.conf
```

Is this solution ok? Is there a better way?

But if I want to comment multiple of line what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is your regex ok? From the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html):
`Replace all instances of a particular string in a file using a back-referenced regular expression`

Can you share parts of your `nova.conf` file.

What you also can do:

```
- name: Comment out a line
  replace:
    dest: /etc/nova/nova.conf
    regexp: "{{ item.exp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
  tags: update-nova.conf
  with_items:
    - { exp: '^connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite', replace: '#connection = sqlite:////var/lib/nova/nova.sqlite'}
    - { exp: 'test', replace: '#test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use backreferences plus `|` and parentheses with different regex expressions.

```
    regexp: '^((1|2).*)$'
    replace: '#\1'
```

This will comment all lines if they start with 1 or 2.